# Find the path to a library when using headless linux image

Tags: linux, bash, gnu

Hi I'm connected to parallella board , using only UART, I'm written and executing codes using only GNU bash, and I don't have a desktop. only that terminal connection

I'm using DevIL library in  a C code, and i receive `undefined reference to`ilInit'` etc..

so I should tell where is the path to DevIL library, what are the GNU bash instructions in order to find the `/path/to/DevIL/lib/dir` and `DevIL lib name`, I try find DevIL , and i receive `no such file or directory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
find / -name libname
```

where `libname` is the name of your library. This will return all paths that contain a file with the name `libname` anywhere in your system. If you have a rough idea of the location, use that path instead of the system root `/` as this will make the command run faster (When called as above the first argument is telling the `find` command what directory to search under).

Libraries usually start with `lib`xyz, so perhaps you should check the name as `DevIL` does not adhere to this convention.

You must know the library name since you will need to pass its name and location as a link option to your C compiler at some point.

Comment: the output for `find / -name DevIL` was nothing